# Selecting second tab stops animation in first tab and does not restart

Tags: ios, animation, tabbar

I create a new tabbed application project in Xcode 4.2 using Storyboards.
In viewDidLoad, I add the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:30
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void) {
                     CGRect imageViewFrame = self.scrollingImageView.frame;
                     imageViewFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(imageViewFrame) / -2;
                     self.scrollingImageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
                 } completion:nil];
```

Then I create the associated UIImageView property and wire it up in IB.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *scrollingImageView;
```

I put an image into the imageview, run it in the simulator or my iPod Touch, and I see scrolling.

However, when I select the second tab and then go back to the first tab, the animation completes what appears to be immediately and I cannot get it to restart, even if I put the above into viewWillAppear. I have searched through lots of answers and cannot solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the issue you are dealing with is specific to tabbed bar controllers, not storyboards or the specific animation. The issue is that when you switch to a different tab, the animation stops, and when you return to the first tab, it doesn't resume.

Ordering the animation again in `viewWillAppear` does not work (as you mentioned), but if you first remove the animation in `viewWillDisappear`, then ordering it again in `viewWillAppear` should work. For example

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]; // or whatever you need to use to remove your specific animation
}
```

NB: The animation removal code should be in `viewWillDisappear` rather than in `viewWillUnload`, since `viewWillUnload` does not get called when you switch tabs.